# Why move assignment is called

Tags: c++11, move, rvalue, lvalue

Please tell me why move assignment is called in the following code.
In expression `return Foo(static_cast<int>(value));`, `static_cast<int>(value)` is rvalue, so move assignment is called. However, in expression `return Foo(value);`, `value` is an lvalue. Why move assignment is called instead of `Foo(int val)`;

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

class Foo {
public:
    Foo() {}

    Foo(int val)
    {
        value = val;
    }

    Foo(Foo& foo)
    {
        value = foo.value;
        cout << "call Foo(Foo& foo)" << endl;
    }

    Foo(Foo&& foo)
    {
        value = foo.value;
        foo.value = 0;
        cout << "call Foo(Foo &&foo)" << endl;
    }

    Foo& operator=(Foo &foo)
    {
        value = foo.value;
        cout << "call operator=(Foo& foo)" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    Foo& operator=(Foo &&foo)
    {
        value = foo.value;
        foo.value = 0;
        cout << "call operator=(Foo&& foo)" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

private:
    int value;
};

Foo operator"" fo(unsigned long long value)
{
    if (value < INT_MAX) {
        // return Foo(static_cast<int>(value)); // call operator=(Foo&& foo)
        return Foo(value);                      // call operator=(Foo&& foo)
    } else {
        throw "Over Range";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo = 123fo;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The value category of the constructor argument will select the right constructor. But the assignment (that happens in main) is something else. `operator=` is called for `foo = 123fo`, not inside `operator""`

Comment: The assignment happens in `foo = 123fo;` and not in `return Foo(value);`.  Also please do not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, it causes global warming.